# How to plot a graph real time using coreplot?

Tags: core-plot

I'm trying to plot the decibel values of sound on a graph(CPScatterPlot) using coreplot. But the problem is I'm getting the graph with a line that is perpendicular for Y axis, and it's moving up and down on the Y axis with respect to the changes in the decibel values. I need to plot a graph like this. [image]

here is my code:
`

```
    -(void) generateDataSamples
    {

     samples = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:NUM_SAMPLES];

     for (int i=0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) 

        {
            // peakVal is a variable that holds the decibel value   
             NSDictionary *sample = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                         
             [NSNumber numberWithDouble:peakVal],Y_VAL,nil];
             [samples addObject:sample];
            } 

    }

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot; 
{
   return [samples count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum 
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

 NSDictionary *sample = [samples objectAtIndex:index];
 NSDecimalNumber *num = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    if (fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX) 
    {
        num = (NSDecimalNumber *) [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:index + 1];
    }
    else if (fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldY)
    {
    return [sample valueForKey:Y_VAL];
    }
    return num; 
}
```

So, what should I do to get a graph as in the figure above? Please help me, I'm new on here.

And one more, as you can in the above picture, the Y axis labels are placed inside the plot area, how it can be done?

Here is my entire code, please suggest the modifications:

```
#import "MicBlowViewController.h"
#import "SecondVC.h"
#define DBOFFSET -74.0
#define START_POINT 0.0
#define END_POINT 100.0
#define NUM_SAMPLES 200.0
#define MAX_PEAK 100.0

#define X_VAL @"X_VAL"
#define Y_VAL @"Y_VAL"
#define S_VAL @"S_VAL"


@implementation MicBlowViewController
@synthesize avgLabel, peakLabel,absValue,pageControl;


-(void)reloadData
{
    if(!graph)
    {
        //setting graph
        double xAxisStart = START_POINT;
        double xAxisLength = END_POINT - START_POINT;
        double maxY = 100;//[[samples valueForKeyPath:@"@max.Y_VAL"] doubleValue];
        double yAxisStart = START_POINT;
        double yAxisLength = maxY+3;
        xVal=START_POINT+0.1;
        hostingView = [[CPGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 79, 320, 361)];
        [self.view  addSubview:hostingView];
        graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 79, 320, 361)];
        hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

        CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPDarkGradientTheme];
        [graph applyTheme:theme];
        graph.paddingTop = 0.0;
        graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;
        graph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
        graph.paddingRight = 0.0;
        [[graph defaultPlotSpace] setAllowsUserInteraction:TRUE];
        CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
        axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset=0.1;
        CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
        x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromDouble(10.0);
        x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromInteger(0);
        x.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;

        CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

        y.majorIntervalLength=CPDecimalFromDouble(10.0);
        y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromInteger(0);
        y.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
        y.tickDirection = CPSignPositive;
        y.labelAlignment = CPAlignmentLeft;
        y.alternatingBandFills = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[CPColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1], [NSNull null], nil];
        CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(xAxisStart)
                                                       length:CPDecimalFromDouble(xAxisLength)];

        plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(yAxisStart)
                                                       length:CPDecimalFromDouble(yAxisLength)];    

        CPScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPScatterPlot alloc] init];
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
        //[dataSourceLinePlot insertDataAtIndex:[samplesY count]-1 numberOfRecords:1];

        CPMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
        lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.f;
        lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor cyanColor];
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

        [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

        [dataSourceLinePlot release];
        [graph release];
        [hostingView release];
    }
}

- (void)generateData
{

       // if (plotData == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            //double test = (double)[peakLabel.text doubleValue];
            absValue.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",peakVal];
            id x = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:1.0 + i ];
            id y = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:peakVal * rand()/(double)RAND_MAX + 0.05];
            [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
        }
        plotData = [contentArray retain];
        //}

}
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot ;
{
    return [plotData count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum 
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{
    NSNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];

    if (fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldY) {
        num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]];

    }
    return num;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]init];
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    samplesY = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //checking for sound
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];

    NSError *error;
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }// else
    //NSLog([error description]);   
}


- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // getting decibel values....
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));

    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  

    NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input: %f Low pass results: %f",
          [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0], lowPassResults);
    peakval=fabs([recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);
    double avgval=fabs([recorder averagePowerForChannel:0]);
    peakVal=MAX_PEAK - peakval;
    avgVal=MAX_PEAK - avgval;
    NSLog(@"First: %.2f",peakVal);

    avgLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",avgVal];
    peakLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",peakVal];
    if (lowPassResults < 0.95)
        NSLog(@"Mic blow detected: %d",lowPassResults);

    [self generateData];

    [self reloadData];

}

- (IBAction) changePage:(id)sender{
    SecondVC *vc = [[SecondVC alloc]init];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [peakLabel.text release];
    [avgLabel.text release];
    [samples release];
    [levelTimer release];
    [recorder release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the same `peakVal` for every data point. Check the `-generateDataSamples` method and make sure you're storing the correct values in the `samples` array. If you already have the data in an array, you can skip that method completely and just do the lookup by index in `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:`.

Also, check the `xRange` and `yRange` on the plot space to make sure they fit your data. Remember that plot ranges are like NSRange—they are created using a starting location and length, not start and end values.

To move the labels to the right side of the y-axis, use `yAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;`.

*Edit in response to the comments*

Don't call `-generateDataSamples` every time you get new data. Instead, add the new value to the `samples` array. Don't forget to initialize the array before using it for the first time.

```
NSDictionary *sample = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                         
    [NSNumber numberWithDouble:peakVal],Y_VAL,nil];
[samples addObject:sample];
```

Once the data is in the array, tell Core Plot to load only the new point. This will be faster than reloading all of the data every time you update.

```
[myScatterPlot insertDataAtIndex:(samples.count - 1)
                 numberOfRecords:1];
```

You can use the CPTPlot method `-deleteDataInIndexRange:` to remove old data points if you don't need to keep all of the history in the graph. Don't forget to remove the corresponding point from the `samples` array also.

Comment: yAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive; is not working in the version of coreplot that I'm using. Needed a small modification, yAxis.tickDirection = CPSignPositive; thank you

Comment: I couldn't make it working yet, if you don't mind would you please make the modifications to the code? I'm new on here, please help me.

Comment: Anybody please help me, I've been working on this for last 3 days, please.

Comment: You're using the same numeric value for every sample. Fix that first. If that doesn't solve your problem, edit your question to add the code you use to set up the graph so we can see what else is going on. A screenshot of what your graph looks like would help, too.

Comment: I've a variable called peakVal. Which is updated at each second with new data. So, I need to plot the graph with respect to this variable. I know, I'm getting the same numeric value for every sample. But how can I get the updated value at each second. Is it possible to store the value in an array in real time and to retrieve it? That's I need to store the variable in an array and at the same time need to retrieve the value from the same array to plot the graph. How can I do that? Please help me, I'm no getting the logic to do that.

Comment: If you can please describe it with a simple example. Hope you can. :-)

Comment: Hey Eric, are you online now?

Comment: where should I put this code                                       [myScatterPlot insertDataAtIndex:(samples.count - 1)
                 numberOfRecords:1];

Comment: I would put that code in `-levelTimerCallback:`, replacing the calls to `-generateData` and `-reloadData`. Add the new data point to the `samples` array in that same method.

Comment: Hey Eric, thank you so much....!!! at last got it... I did as you said, now its working fine and I'm getting the real time plotting of values. may god bless you.

Comment: Eric, I'm very much interested in Core plot, and I would like to learn more about it. is there any tutorial available for this?. Than you.

Comment: There aren't any official tutorials available yet. There are a number of sample programs included with Core Plot in the examples folder. I just added a real-time plot to the Plot Gallery example app to demonstrate some of the things we've discussed here.